# coredns will not start on the vagrant ubuntu/impish64 image but will start and run successfully with ubuntu/bionic

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to run k8s on ubuntu/impish64. I have a reference env that is successfully running ubuntu/bionic.  The only differences between the environments is the ubuntu image and ip address ranges

This is the Bionic output:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE    IP              NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
coredns-64897985d-bk74z            1/1     Running   2 (3d2h ago)   4d8h   10.244.0.6      machine1   <none>           <none>
coredns-64897985d-jhghl            1/1     Running   2 (3d2h ago)   4d8h   10.244.0.7      machine1   <none>           <none>
etcd-machine1                      1/1     Running   2 (3d2h ago)   4d8h   192.168.33.20   machine1   <none>           <none>
kube-apiserver-machine1            1/1     Running   2 (3d2h ago)   4d8h   192.168.33.20   machine1   <none>           <none>
kube-controller-manager-machine1   1/1     Running   2 (3d2h ago)   4d8h   192.168.33.20   machine1   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-7c6mh              1/1     Running   2 (3d2h ago)   4d8h   192.168.33.20   machine1   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-r982l                   1/1     Running   2 (3d2h ago)   4d8h   192.168.33.20   machine1   <none>           <none>
kube-scheduler-machine1            1/1     Running   2 (3d2h ago)   4d8h   192.168.33.20   machine1   <none>           <none>
```

This is the impish output:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-impish:~$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
coredns-64897985d-bd47f            0/1     Pending   0          45m   <none>      <none>     <none>           <none>
coredns-64897985d-s9bct            0/1     Pending   0          45m   <none>      <none>     <none>           <none>
etcd-machine1                      1/1     Running   0          45m   10.0.2.15   machine1   <none>           <none>
kube-apiserver-machine1            1/1     Running   0          45m   10.0.2.15   machine1   <none>           <none>
kube-controller-manager-machine1   1/1     Running   0          45m   10.0.2.15   machine1   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-2sknk                   1/1     Running   0          45m   10.0.2.15   machine1   <none>           <none>
kube-scheduler-machine1            1/1     Running   0          45m   10.0.2.15   machine1   <none>           <none>
```

Two potentially telling clues are:

```
Jan 21 09:22:21 ubuntu-impish kubelet[8744]: I0121 09:22:21.657003    8744 cni.go:240] "Unable to update cni config" err="no networks found in /etc/cni/net.d"

Jan 21 09:22:24 ubuntu-impish kubelet[8744]: E0121 09:22:24.425056    8744 kubelet.go:2347] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized"
```

Attempting to install flannel fails with the following:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-impish:~$ sudo kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to the community! You're running last command with `sudo` and getting the error because there's no `kubectl config` under root user. Try to run without `sudo`, should do the trick

Comment: The above mentioned suggestion does make sense. @Dwight Have you tried it?

Comment: @moonkotte. Thank you! it worked.   Rajesh Dutta yes.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the answer out of comments.

---

The answer is very short:

Last command should be executed without `sudo` because there's no context created for `kubectl` under `root` user.

You can check `config` in `~/.kube/config`

Comment: Hello @DwightJ.Browne and welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!